# Speeding up a sql query that uses exists

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, optimization

I'm new to SQL and have managed to finally put together a query that returns the values I'm looking for! The only problem is, this runs really slowly, presumably because of the exists clause. I was hoping that adding LIMIT would speed things up significantly, but unfortunately I found out empirically that this isn't true.

Is there another way to write this query that returns the same values at an "acceptable" speed? I realize that "acceptable" is subjective, but I'm just looking for new approaches.

Here are the tables used:

```
content
---------------------------------------
id            |    Int
---------------------------------------

content_revision
---------------------------------------
id            |    Int
content_id    |    ForeignKey (content)
---------------------------------------
```

Here is my slow query:

```
SELECT outer_content.id AS "TEN_MOST_RECENT_CONTENTS_WITH_ONE_REVISION" 
    FROM content outer_content 
    JOIN content_revision ON outer_content.id = content_revision.content_id 
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT inner_content.id 
            FROM content_revision 
            JOIN content inner_content ON content_revision.content_id = inner_content.id 
            WHERE outer_content.id = inner_content.id 
            GROUP BY inner_content.id HAVING count(*) = 1
    ) 
ORDER BY ts_created DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

I'm interested in finding the "TEN_MOST_RECENT_CONTENTS_WITH_ONE_REVISION"

Comment: Generate an execution plan and look at the most expensive operations (a good DBA can help tremendously).  An index on `ts_created` will likely help.  Note that `LIMIT` doesn't help the actual query performance since it will likely need to scan the whole table to find the "top 10" results.

Comment: Can't you just use `SELECT inner_content.id 
            FROM content_revision 
            JOIN content inner_content ON content_revision.content_id = inner_content.id 
            GROUP BY inner_content.id HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY ts_created DESC 
LIMIT 10;`

Comment: @artm - I was hoping to be able to do something like this, unfortunately this causes an error... Because I'm grouping by ```inner_content.id```, I can't ORDER BY ts_created because there may be multiple columns that are grouped together with different ts_created. Grouping by both columns will undo the GROUP BY statement because the ts_created values are essentially all unique. :(

Comment: @RobertKotcher add `max(ts_created)` to the select list and `order by max(ts_created) desc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need the inner select? You can use:

```
 SELECT inner_content.id, MAX(ts_created) 
            FROM content_revision 
            JOIN content inner_content ON content_revision.content_id = inner_content.id 
            GROUP BY inner_content.id HAVING count(*) = 1
            ORDER BY MAX(ts_created) DESC 
            LIMIT 10;
```

Since you're using a group by, if you want to order by `ts_created`, you can use `MAX(ts_created)`. There's only one record anyway because of the `HAVING`

Comment: This seems to be working! Let me play around with it for a few more minutes, and if it's doing what I'm expecting, I'll upvote. Thanks!

Comment: A thing you will need to check here is the order of your rows, `MAX(ts_created)` will always evaluate to one date and it may mess up with the results that you are expecting.

Comment: @JorgeCampos `MAX(ts_created)` will return max date for each result in content_revision. So it won't return a single date but the MAX date for each content, so order by will still work.

Comment: @RobertKotcher Out of curiosity, how much did this improve the speed?

Comment: @artm By orders of magnitude!! My original query: ```(cost=2400404.10..2400411.97 rows=3146 width=12)``` Your query: ```(cost=1131.91..1131.93 rows=10 width=12)```. Your solution was really insightful

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `WHERE EXISTS` condition at all. All you have to do is `GROUP BY content.id, content.ts_created` and add `HAVING count(content_revision.*) = 1`, then limit, order, etc...

```
-- get ten most recent contents with one revision
SELECT content.id, content.ts_created 
FROM content
JOIN content_revision ON content.id = content_revision.content_id 
GROUP BY content.id, content.ts_created 
HAVING count(content_revision.*) = 1
ORDER BY content.ts_created DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. You wil get the `column "content.ts_created" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` This is not MySql where you can do such a thing

Comment: @JorgeCampos you're right. I missed that. I fixed the query.

Comment: That will likely not give the result op wants since it will group by ID and TS_CREATED where he only wants to group by ID.

Comment: This is still incorrect - GROUP BY X, Y means that a row will be generated for all sets of rows containing _both_ X & Y.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I disagree. Indeed it will group by ID and TS_CREATED. But since ID is a unique field (I hope so), it will not produce duplicate rows.

Comment: OP is joining with other table which means that likely ID will be duplicated that's why he is grouping by it otherwise the group by wouldn't be needed anyway because all rows would have just one ID

Comment: @RobertKotcher have you tried to run my query? It must produce the exact same result as you wanted.

Comment: @JorgeCampos `id` and `ts_created` are the columns of one table - `contents`. So grouping by content.id, content.ts_created WILL NOT produce duplicated rows.

Comment: @pumbo Thanks for offering your help. I was actually trying to run this same query myself a little eariler, but ran into the issue that I describe above. The solution artm posted addresses the problems with this query. I didn't understand the subtleties in the relationship between GROUP BY and ORDER BY myself until right now.

Comment: Create a table with these values and test it you will see duplicated values: 1-20160302 / 1-20160301 / 1-20160303 / 2-20160401. The count for each row here will return 1 because you are grouping two values. You are assuming that the date is the same for all rows.

Comment: Here, take a look at this sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a6ff3/1 you will see how group by works. The only rows that will not return is 2-c and 6-a because they are only ones that is duplicated, entire row, id AND somevalue

Comment: @JorgeCampos I got your point. But it is `id` column. Do you really believe there's a slight chance of `id` column not being unique (primary key)?

Comment: What you didn't see is that it is a JOIN operation, so if there are more than one ID on the second table (foreign key for `content_revision.content_id`) it will be duplicated. IF it was just the `content` table I would totally agree with you (assuming that id is unique of course).

Comment: @JorgeCampos take a look at `group by` statement in my example more carefully, and tell: can `GROUP BY content.id, content.ts_created` produce duplicate records? No. Only if `content.id` is not a unique column.

Comment: I think I may take the wrong course on our discussion here, maybe somewhere I lead you to think that I was arguing about the duplicate results. That's not it, I'm arguing about the COUNT results that will be duplicated I mean if there are id=1 and date=A (just as example) and id=1 and date=B, you are right when you say that it is not duplicated, but for what OP wants it is since he only wants the count by ID and for that it will be duplicated because for each of that rows the count will be 1 then he will have id=1 UNLESS the dates are equal which would lead to wrong results

Comment: @JorgeCampos I need to clarify something. Did I get it right that `ts_created` is a column of table `content` ? I assumed so although OP never mentioned it. If `ts_created` is a column of `content` then its not possible to have `id=1, ts_created=A` and `id=1, ts_created=B` in the same table. But if `ts_created` is a column of `content_revision` then I totally messed up, and in that case you're right.

Comment: Well, with that I have to agree with you, I was assuming that ts_created was from `content_revision` and if it wasn't you were right all the time. sorry for wasting both our times...